# using firebase database trigger with react

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am trying to create an event in my React web-app when my firebase database gets updated.

```
import fire from '../../config/Fire';
....
componentDidMount = () => {
    let self = this
    let database = fire.database().ref();
    let userId = this.state.userId
    database.onUpdate(event => {
        console.log('eve', event)
    })
}
```

In my `componentDidMount`, I just simply tried to console.log it to see if it works, but I get an error: `TypeError: database.onUpdate is not a function`

I followed this page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events?hl=en

But it is not exactly for React.

I wonder how I have to use it.

**EDIT**

`fire.js`

```
import firebase from 'firebase';


const fire = firebase.initializeApp(config);
export default fire;
```

My config includes the API key.

Comment: can you share what do you have in `config/Fire`? What exactly is `fire`?

Comment: @HristoEftimov I edited my question. `fire.js` looks like that.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran across this question, but it looks to me like you aren't calling the firebase object correctly. This is why you were getting the undefined function error. While you did import it, I would not set
`fire = firebase.initializeApp(config)`
All you need to do is:
`import * as fire from 'firebase';`
Then you can call your firebase functions and references like:
`fire.database().ref();`